# Is detuning a bowl back mandolin's strings necessary?

Tags: mandolin

I have been reading here the questions and answers regarding, de-tuning, or loosening the strings on a guitar every day at the end of each practice session. From the many answers it is clear to me that there is no need for this practice unless the instrument is stored for a long time. However, I wonder if this also applies to a mandolin, as I have a new bowl back mandolin, built in Italy, and I know that the tension on the neck is about 80 Kg, which seems enormous to me on an instrument which looks so delicate. I practice 2 hours a day and re-tuning and de-tuning every day would be quite annoying.

Comment: Can't see why any instrument would be produced, knowing it needed slackening off after every play. All of my guitars (acoustic/electric/classical) and basses are kept, mostly hanging, in tune, to be taken down and played straightaway. They have been like that for over 20 years. Maybe mandolins are different, but I doubt it. A fellow player uses one, and that's always (nearly!) in tune.

Comment: To add on @Tim , I would say applying and releasing the tension regularly can actually *damage* the instrument as the constraints on the wood will always change, wearing it over time. If kept always under tension, nothing moves which is probably for the wood (and not to mention that instruments are actually designed to be under tension… Imagine a piano for which it would not be the case…).

Comment: It would be good if you could provide links to the QAs you refer to - some answers might need some down-votes ;))

Comment: Thanks so much guys for your prompt reply to my question, i did think that was the case but just wanted to ask around, people who knows better than myself. most grateful, thank you.

Comment: I have an A-style mandolin and keep it in tune. I don't know from bowl-backs, though. If you were _shipping_, it, or putting it into longer-term storage, I'd consider detuning, but be aware that the bridge might be held on by tension alone

Answer (score 2):

I've never untuned the strings of my bowl-back mandolin after playing. Admittedly though, I own it only for a little less than a year and I use ultra light strings (but the gauge should usually not matter for a modern instrument).

Another point to consider: If you think that the mandolin is an especially small and delicate stringed instrument, do not forget the violin. A quick Google search showed that [violinists usually do not untune their strings](https://www.violinist.com/blog/Zlata/20137/14816/) after playing. If it is safe for the violin to keep the strings in tune when not played it should also be safe for the mandolin.

Comment: Just suggest to a historically informed violinist to relax their gut strings after playing. That'd be fun, when before playing you'll need to spend an hour again getting the strings even _roughly_ in tune...